# Alternative to Matplotlib for scientific plotting with Python

Tags: python, scientific-computing, plotting

I can't take anymore Matplotlib's general approach of "plotting-by-side-effect".

Is there an alternative?

I'm looking for something closer in philosophy to Mathematica's `Plot` function, which returns a stand-alone `Graphics` object.  This object encapsulates all the information needed to render the corresponding image.  There's no notion of "the current figure" or "the current axes".

(I'm looking for something that I can use comfortably from python code.)

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! What exact features do you need? Please check with [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) for possible improvements of your question, increasing the chances for good and matching answers :)

Comment: @Izzy: to put it bluntly, I want to be able to plot from Python anything I can plot from *Mathematica*.  I know this won't happen in my lifetime, so I'm looking for the closest approximation to this utopian ideal.  ("Why not just use Mathematica?"  Because I work in a group where most people know only Python, at best.)

Comment: Thanks for the update, kjo – but that should be part of the question itself. Remember, you can always [edit] your posts :) (I'm not familiar with *Mathematica* – but if "anything I can plot from Mathematica" is not self-explaining, you might need to elaborate on that as well)

Comment: Note that while plotting by side effect is the primarily advertised way of using Matplotlib, it is not obligatory. For an introduction to object-oriented plotting, see [this](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/lifecycle.html).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a few alternatives that you might wish to look at:

- [plot.ly](https://plot.ly/) this does some very nice things and may be more of the style you would like, it can now be used offline and does tricks like embedding the java into a web page so as to give scrollable, zooming, etc., graphs - for python, R & Matlab it is free, open source and self hosted *for Excel not so*.
- [bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) - again nice graphs - can be used from R, Scala & Julia as well as python.
- [ggplot](http://ggplot.yhathq.com/) - To quote the authors "ggplot sacrafices highly customization in favor of generall doing "what you'd expect"."
- [New] [Cartify][4](https://labs.spotify.com/2018/11/15/introducing-chartify-easier-chart-creation-in-python-for-data-scientists/) gives a much more restrictive number of charts but aims to make life a lot simpler, (and more Object Oriented).
- The old favourite [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) - very powerful but not necessarily the easiest to use and many of the examples you will find are based on the pyplot MATLAB style concept of the current current figure/axis - however it also provides an OO interface some examples of which you can find [here](https://medium.com/@kapil.mathur1987/matplotlib-an-introduction-to-its-object-oriented-interface-a318b1530aed) so simply use it that way instead.

There is a nice overview [here](http://pbpython.com/visualization-tools-1.html) of some of the less painful to use visualisation tools.

### From the comments of others *not tried by me*

- [Altair](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair) - Altair is a declarative statistical visualization library for Python. *([ostrokach](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/27611/ostrokach))*
- [plotnine](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) plotnine is an implementation of a grammar of graphics in Python, it is based on ggplot2. *([hatshepsut](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/18950/hatshepsut))*

Comment: Landed on this because of bugs in the matplotlib library for Python. Plot.ly and ggplot both rely on matplotlib. Bokeh doesn't, so for anyone needing to get around bugs in matplotlib, its an alternative.

Comment: Add [Altair](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair) to the list.

Comment: [Plotnine](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gallery.html) is [the best](http://pltn.ca/plotnine-superior-python-ggplot/) ggplot implementation in python.

Comment: plot.ly would allow only one private plot, wouldn't it? Not sure if I want every plot to be public shared. Looking for other interactive plot alternatives.

Comment: @EduardoReis - If you use plot.ly __offline__ then all of the plots are private, in fact they are not even online unless you manually post them somewhere.

Comment: @SteveBarnes, why would you list matplotlib (4th on your list) as an alternative to itself.

Comment: @alancalvitti: _Well spotted!_ In fact it is possible to use matplotlib without the plot by-side-effect annoyance - expanded that item to make that clearer.

Comment: @SteveBarnes, OP specifically asked for a Mathematica-like Graphics system. This is functional language, with no side effects, while OO langs work via side effects.

Comment: @alancalvitti OP specifically asked for a package that "returns an __object__ that encapsulates all the information needed to render the corresponding image" - that is exactly what using matplotlib in an object based manner does! In fact that it the point of OO langs.

Comment: @SteveBarnes, Graphics are not objects in Mathematica, there's no attributes or methods - which is what makes it side-effect-free.

Answer (score 7):

I'm developing advance PyQt applications and the main reason for not using Mathplotlib was that you can't create realtime complex graphs in 3D and 2D that updates at 60fps!

So I use: [**pyQtGraph** Scientific Graphics and GUI Library for Python](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/) that uses OpenGL :)

> PyQtGraph is a pure-python graphics and GUI library built on PyQt4 / PySide and numpy. It is intended for use in mathematics / scientific / engineering applications. Despite being written entirely in python, the library is very fast due to its heavy leverage of numpy for number crunching and Qt's GraphicsView framework for fast display. PyQtGraph is distributed under the MIT open-source license.

Some of example from web page and my own examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @user11879, is  pyQtGraph current? documentation seems dated at circa 2011 and using PyQt4, not 5?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/ is also an option.

It is a Python wrapper around the much used and mature VTK.

The advantages are e.g. hardware acceleration for 1M+ points, nice shaders and full control of the scene (e.g. lighting).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).