# Alternative to Matplotlib for interactive plotting in Python

Tags: library, python, math, plotting

I need a plotting library which can be used for interactive plotting and generate plots directly from the command line. Plotly and Bokeh are good but they are meant to be used with web applications. I need to display the plots like matplotlib from the command line (in a new window and not the browser) which doesn't seem to be possible with the other libraries.

Is there any good alternative?

Comment: What is missing for you in matplotlib?

Comment: I want an interactive plot which can be panned or zoomed. In matplotlib, this feature is not very smooth.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternative to Matplotlib for scientific plotting with Python](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27240/alternative-to-matplotlib-for-scientific-plotting-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

If you would use Java as a backed of your Python code, you may look at [DataMelt program](https://jwork.org/dmelt).  Here is the gallery of images you can create with DataMelt:

https://jwork.org/dmelt/showcase/index.php

Note that that you can program code snippets in Jython (Python implemented in Java), so you can easily reuse your CPython code inside DataMelt. But you need to use Java classes that make such plots.

Comment: Please disclose any affiliation you have with this product.

Comment: I'm a web admin where this (and many other) program is posted. Not associated with the program itself.